# IText 7 - How to send PDF through a Rest Api without storing file ?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

This is the first time i'm using the library iText 7.
I would like to send the pdf generated through my `@Get` http response without storing the file on my server. 
I tried this :

```
@GET
@Path("/generatePDF")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
public Response generatePDF() {
    try {

        String text ="This is the text of my pdf";
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));

        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);            
        doc.add(new Paragraph(text));
        doc.close();
        System.err.println("doc closed");


        return Response.ok().entity(baos).
                header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\"mypdf - " + new Date().toString() + ".pdf\"")
                .header("Expires", "0")
                .header("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
                .header("Pragma", "public")
                .build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

But I'm facing the following error :

> GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/octet-stream, type=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream, genericType=class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.

Do you have any idea how to do this ? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried using `Response.ok().entity(baos.toByteArray())...` instead of `Response.ok().entity(baos)...`?

Comment: No more error with this. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

`Response` expects `InputStream` rather than `OutputStream`. So just re-wrap your bytes into `InputStream` and send the response:

```
ByteArrayInputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
return Response.ok().entity(pdfStream);
```

Comment: Thank you too :) 
I used baos.toByteArray() directly to avoid the creation of an temp object :)